# Add/Change Column Name on Internal Table ALV

Tags: abap, alv

What I need is to add titles to these two columns (highlighted in yellow) and I don't know how to do that.

[image: Columns without the titles]

```
FORM display_alv. 
    DATA: gr_functions TYPE REF TO cl_salv_functions.
    DATA: gr_display TYPE REF TO cl_salv_display_settings.    
    DATA: gr_columns TYPE REF TO cl_salv_columns_table.    
    DATA: gr_column TYPE REF TO cl_salv_column_table.    
    DATA: gr_sorts TYPE REF TO cl_salv_sorts.    
    DATA: gr_agg TYPE REF TO cl_salv_aggregations.    
    DATA: gr_selections TYPE REF TO cl_salv_selections.
    
    gr_functions = alv->get_functions( ).    
    gr_functions->set_all( abap_true ).
    
    gr_display = alv->get_display_settings( ).    
    gr_display->set_striped_pattern( cl_salv_display_settings=>true ).    
    gr_display->set_list_header( 'Relatório RVs' ).
    
    gr_columns = alv->get_columns( ).    
    gr_columns->set_optimize( 'X' ).    
    gr_columns = alv->get_columns( ).
    
    gr_column ?= gr_columns->get_column( 'revenue' ).    
    gr_column->set_short_text( 'Revenue' ).    
    gr_column->set_medium_text( 'Revenue' ).
    
    alv->display( ).
ENDFORM.
```

Comment: You could either change it in your program or fix it via transaction SE11. But without code...

Comment: @lausek can i fix an internal table via the transaction SE11? How?

Comment: You can adjust the data element in the internal tables structure. At least if it is a non-standard one. Please add some code to your question.

Comment: @lausek just added the code

Comment: Please, format your code properly.

Comment: i will replace it with an image to be easier

Comment: Is it a custom defined table? or an SAP standard table?

Comment: It is a custom defined table

Comment: Hi @TheAndréGomes, I edited your post (queue'd at the moment) to have the code formatted in the post. SO is pretty strict on formatting and how to ask questions. It takes time to figure out all of the nuances. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for some of these ALV-methods are pretty finicky. I'm pretty sure that your code is right, except that `revenue` needs to be in all caps. See the example below:

```
alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'REVENUE' )->set_short_text( 'Revenue' ) ##NO_TEXT.
alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'REVENUE' )->set_medium_text( 'Revenue' ) ##NO_TEXT.
alv->get_columns( )->get_column( 'REVENUE' )->set_long_text( 'Revenue' ) ##NO_TEXT.
```

Comment: Thank you @gkubed thats exactly it!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: In general (or in my experience 99% of the cases) if you use DDIC element names / field names / program names / etc. in any parameter you have to go with uppercase, because it is stored this way in DB and not every API convert them before accessing. The best way to eliminate these types of errors is the use of uppercase.